# Dynamic form with TextInput in a FlatList issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, textinput

Actual Behaviour :

I'm loading a dynamic form in a FlatList and I'm supposed to add few rows with TextInputs based on a condition. For example, I have a checkbox. When I check the checkbox, I have to add a dropdown and two TextInputs and when I uncheck the checkbox, I have to remove these three. My issue is that when I check the checkbox and enter some value in the TextInputs and uncheck the checkbox, then the value in the last TextInput is getting assigned to another TextInput which is not related to these conditions.

Expected Behaviour :

The last TextInput value should not get assigned to another TextInput which is not related to checkbox conditions on unchecking the checkbox.

Here is my code for the TextInput :

```
 _onChangeText(e, item, index) {
    console.log("abc123 ", item);
    let count = "false";
    let note;
    if (this.state.inputsValues.length === 0 && item.blocks.question !== undefined) {
        if (item.blocks.question.prompt !== "Notes") {
            note = {
                note: e.nativeEvent.text.replace(/\n/g, ''),
                id: item.blocks.question.prompt
            };
        } else {
            note = {
                note: e.nativeEvent.text.replace(/\n/g, ''),
                id: item.blocks.block_pos
            };
        }
        this.setState({ inputsValues: [...this.state.inputsValues, note] }, () => {
            console.log("length === 0", this.state.inputsValues);
        });
    } else {
        this.state.inputsValues.map((res, idx) => {
            if (item.blocks.question !== undefined && res.id === item.blocks.question.prompt) {
                res.note = e.nativeEvent.text.replace(/\n/g, '');
                count = "true";
            }
        });
        if (count === "false") {
            if (item.blocks.question.prompt !== "Notes") {
                note = {
                    note: e.nativeEvent.text.replace(/\n/g, ''),
                    id: item.blocks.question.prompt
                };
            } else {
                note = {
                    note: e.nativeEvent.text.replace(/\n/g, ''),
                    id: item.blocks.block_pos
                };
            }
            this.setState({ inputsValues: [...this.state.inputsValues, note] }, () => {
                // console.log("gvrtgrtgt", this.state.inputsValues);
            });
        }
    }
}
<NBTextField
itemStyles={[styles.itemStyles, { height: width / 6 }]}
value={inputsValues[index] !== undefined && inputsValues[index].note}
onEndEditing={e => this._onChangeText(e, item)}
onChangeText={this.getInputValue}
onSubmitEditing={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
inputStyles={[styles.inputStyles, { height: width / 6 }]}
placeholder="Enter here"
/>
```

Environment :

> react-native : 0.61.1

Screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me in mycase

```
 _onChangeText(e, item, index) {
    if (item.blocks.block_type === 'question') {
      this.state.mainData[index].answer = e.nativeEvent.text;
      this.setState({
        mainData: this.state.mainData,
      });
    }
  }
   <NBTextField
       itemStyles={styles.itemStyles}
       value={item.answer}
       onEndEditing={e => this._onChangeText(e, item, index)}
       onChangeText={e => this.getInputValue(e, item, index)}
       onSubmitEditing={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
       inputStyles={styles.inputStyles}
      />
```